# Need to stop an intensive function with a tap in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, exit, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have a function that analyzes the current image in the camera then displays the analysis on the screen every second. However, the analysis of the image is quite memory-intense and I want to be able to stop the process any time I want and retrieve the data on the screen. I used `UITapGestureRecognizer` to listen for a tap and attempt to "freeze" the analysis on the screen.

Problem is, `UITapGestureRecognizer` waits for the memory-intense function to complete, and therefore will freeze the screen with the NEXT analysis, not the one that was on screen when I tap it.

Is there a way to maybe halt or exit a function when user taps the screen?

Here is my current code:

```
var analyzedText:String
var didTap:Bool
var savedText:String

func timerCalled(timer:NSTimer) {    // timer is on 1 second delay
    let image = capturePhoto()
    if (didTap) {
        savedText = label.text       // "freeze" it
    }
    let text = analyze(image)        // memory-intense function
    label.text = text                // update UILabel
    didTap = false
}

func didTap(tapGR: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    didTap = true
}
```

`savedText` keeps being the next value that appears, not the value that `label.text` was when the screen was tapped.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When running a heavy operation you should always use a background thread.

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
    let text = analyze(image)    

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        // If you do any updates to the user interface they need to go here so that it's put back on the main thread.
        label.text = text           
    }
}
```

pausing the operation is a different matter however. You will have to implement a paus action in the analyzation loop. The background ahead does help you not block the UI though.

To implement some paus functionality in your analyse you would need to check at points in your function if the user has requested a paus and if that has happened you'd need to save the state of the analyzation and quit the operation. Then if the operation were to start up again you'd restore from the state you saved at the paus.